# XML Claims File Digital Signature signed with Smart Card is invalid

Tags: c#, xml, ssl, rsa, x509certificate

#### XML File DSig (Digital Signature) by Smart Card is invalid

I am trying to sign XML Files with Smart Cards. The physical Smart Cards I use are called `SafeNet eToken` and `Yubikey from Yubico`. I also use fully digital Smart Cards. For this question I will go with the `SafeNet eToken`. This Smart Card has a certificate on it which is visible in the `Windows Certificate Store` when you plug the USB stick in. It is a `RSA Certificate` and has Public Key and Private Key. You can install the certificate onto the machine, however you need the USB stick for the Private Key. Also you need the PIN for the Private Key and the correct driver must be installed.

Now I have a C# method which takes an XML File by using the path where it is saved and loading it to a `XmlDocument` object and pass it as a parameter. Also I get the certificate from the `Windows Certificate Store` using the name of the Smart Card and I pass this certificate as a parameter too.

When I execute the method the client of the `SafeNet eToken` starts and asks for the PIN. When the PIN is entered correctly the file gets signed using the Private Key of the Smart Card. The XML File gets saved at the path I wrote and when I read it everything looks fine. It is visible that the XML File was signed and the canonization worked too.

However when I try to verify the XML Digital Signature on [Chilkat Tools](http://tools.chilkat.io/xmlDsigVerify) I get an error message that my signature is invalid everytime. I tried the verification method from .NET itself and some other tools and I always got the same result. The signature is invalid. It didn't matter which Smart Card I used. It seems like it works with all of them, however at the end the Signature is invalid.

Now I had a hard time to find out why exactly this happens. Check out the answer to find out why.

```cs
        /// <summary>
        /// Signs an XMLDocument with additional Keyinfo with a Smart Card. 
        /// The Smart Card can be physical like a Yubikey from Yubico or completely digitally.
        /// Access to the private key of the certificate is mandatory.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="claimsDocument"></param>
        /// <param name="cert"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public void SignClaimsDocument(XmlDocument claimsDocument, X509Certificate2 cert)
        {
            // Variables
            const string outputPath = @"C:\Example\User\Files\signed_claims";
            
            SignedXml signedClaims = new SignedXml(claimsDocument)
            {
                // Add the key to the SignedXml document.
                SigningKey = cert.GetRSAPrivateKey()
            };

            // Create a reference to be signed. Letting the Uri variable empty means that the whole XML will be signed.
            Reference reference = new Reference
            {
                Uri = ""
            };

            // Add an enveloped transformation to the reference.
            reference.AddTransform(new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform());

            // Add canonicalization transformation to the reference using C14N Type.
            reference.AddTransform(new XmlDsigC14NTransform());

            // Add the reference to the SignedXml object.
            signedClaims.AddReference(reference);

            // Include the public key of the certificate in the assertion.
            KeyInfo keyinfo = new KeyInfo();

            // Add Keyinfo
            KeyInfoX509Data kiData = new KeyInfoX509Data();
            kiData.AddSubjectName(cert.SubjectName.Name);
            kiData.AddCertificate(cert);
            keyinfo.AddClause(kiData);

            // RSAKeyValue
            RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaprovider = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PublicKey.Key;
            RSAKeyValue rkv = new RSAKeyValue(rsaprovider);
            keyinfo.AddClause(rkv);

            signedClaims.KeyInfo = keyinfo;

            try
            {
                // Computes the signature using signedClaims.SigningKey. This happens because we give no parameter to the ComputeSignature method.
                signedClaims.ComputeSignature();
            }
            catch (CryptographicException cex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(cex);
                throw cex;
            }

            // Get the XML representation of the signature and save
            // it to an XmlElement object.
            XmlElement xmlDigitalSignature = signedClaims.GetXml();

            // Appends the element to the XML document.
            claimsDocument.DocumentElement?.AppendChild(claimsDocument.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignature, true));

            // Saves the signed XML Claims File at the given path
            claimsDocument.Save(outputPath + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("mm/HH-dd/MM/yyyy") + ".xml");
    
        }
```